# iOS & bootstrap connecting to external database

Tags: android, ios, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing some investigation into developing a iOS App, Android App as well as a bootstrap website. This is really at the early stages of the project and I have been out of software development for a number of years so I am a little rusty, so please forgive me for my questions.

1. To connect to an external database and/or external C# code from an App, I presume you need to use a webservice? Is this the only way to do this?
2. What format is required? JSON?
3. From a bootstrap website, how would I go about doing the same thing? Via a AJAX call to a webservice?
4. Do most Apps use the internal storage/database for storing data? (I know that's a very general question, I am just trying to get a feel for things)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You will need a web service. Theoretically you can connect to the databases directly with android and iOS, but that's less secure, and making changes is difficult. For example, if you ever want to rename a column in your database, you would break your existing apps. However, if you use a webservice, you can update the webservice to report the column under it's old name.
2. You can use whatever format you want, but I would strongly recommend JSON. There are lots of powerful, fast parsers out there to handle serializing and deserializing JSON strings out there, and some networking clients that will even handle the translation automatically for you.
3. You would indeed use an AJAX call.
4. Yes, that is very general, but most apps will. It really varies what kind of data you need to persist. If you're just looking to cache a feed until the next launch you may use a simple file storage (in iOS you can use a NSKeyedArchiver to quickly build objects into a file format and NSKeyedUnarchiver to build objects from a file), or if you need more complex data relationships you would use a SQLite database on the device. On iOS you should use Core Data to manage the SQLite store for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are correct. To get data from an external database you will need to make a webservice call To a script that returns the data you wish to use.
2. You can get the data back in JSON or XML format. I prefer JSON as I think it is easier and simpler.
3. AJAX would be a good way to make calls for your data.
4. Its a good idea to make a mix of both. You can use and webserver to store all your data but if the user is in an area that they can't use data then it would render your app useless. Normally I keep all the data I need on a server then download and store it in the apps DB for that user. You can then make a request to the server at intervals to see if there is any new data to be downloaded. I would suggest doing a similar thing for the bootstrap site.